# React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'getData', 'isAuthorized', and 'props'. Either include them or remove the dependency array

Tags: reactjs

"React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'getData', 'isAuthorized', and 'props'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. However, 'props' will change when *any* prop changes, so the preferred fix is to destructure the 'props' object outside of the useEffect call and refer to those specific props inside useEffect"

This is the warning I got when I'm trying to use useEffect. How can I solve this?

```
useEffect(() => {
        props.handleHeaderTitle("Approval State");
        getData();
        isAuthorized();
    }, [projectId])
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies

Comment: you need to add then to dependency list, the array in which you have written projectID, eg. [getData, isAuthorized, props]

Comment: Thank you @RIYAJKHAN. I found a solution from React documentation